# Data not added to database

Tags: database, codeigniter

been trying to solve what the problem is regarding my code. Haven't had programmed codeigniter for a long time. When I click the ADD ITEM BUTTON, it just stays on the same page and nothing is happening.. Here is my view and model function:

View:

```
    <form action="<?php echo base_url().'item/addItem' ?> " method="post">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Name of Patient</label>
                        <input type="name" class="form-control" name="patient_name" placeholder="Name Here" value="<?php echo set_value('patient_name'); ?>">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Age</label>
                        <input type="input" class="form-control" name="age" placeholder="Age Here" value="<?php echo set_value('age'); ?>">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Date</label>
                        <input type="date" class="form-control" name="date" placeholder="Date" value="<?php echo set_value('date'); ?>">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Grade/PD</label>
                        <input type="input" class="form-control" name="grade" placeholder="Grade/PD Here" value="<?php echo set_value('grade'); ?>">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Frame No.</label>
                        <input type="input" class="form-control" name="frame_no" placeholder="Frame No. Here" value="<?php echo set_value('frame_no'); ?>">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Frame Amount</label>
                        <input type="input" class="form-control" name="frame_amo" placeholder="Frame Amount Here" value="<?php echo set_value('frame_amo'); ?>">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Lens Type/Amount</label>
                        <input type="input" class="form-control" name="lens_typeamo" placeholder="Lens Type/Amount Here" value="<?php echo set_value('lens_typeamo'); ?>">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Laboratory</label>
                        <input type="input" class="form-control" name="labo" placeholder="Laboratory Here" value="<?php echo set_value('labo'); ?>">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Total Amount</label>
                        <input type="input" class="form-control" name="total" placeholder="Total Amount Here" value="<?php echo set_value('total'); ?>">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Saleslady</label>
                        <input type="input" class="form-control" name="saleslady" placeholder="Saleslady Name Here" value="<?php echo set_value('saleslady'); ?>">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Doctor</label>
                        <input type="input" class="form-control" name="doctor" placeholder="Doctor Name Here" value="<?php echo set_value('doctor'); ?>">
                    </div>


                    <a href="<?php echo base_url().'item/itemlistadmin'?>" class="btn btn-info " role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span> BACK </a>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> ADD ITEM</button>
                </form>
```

I'm not sure if what i typed in this area are correct :C

Model:

```
    public function addItem(){

        $patient_name = $this->input->post('patient_name');
        $age = $this->input->post('age');
        $date = $this->input->post('date');
        $grade = $this->input->post('grade');
        $frame_no = $this->input->post('frame_no');
        $frame_amo = $this->input->post('frame_amo');
        $lens_typeamo = $this->input->post('lens_typeamo');
        $labo = $this->input->post('labo');
        $total = $this->input->post('total');                       
        $saleslady = $this->input->post('saleslady');
        $doctor = $this->input->post('doctor'); 


        $item = array(
            'px_name' => $patient_name,
            'px_age' => $age,
            'px_date' => $date,
            'px_grade' => $grade,
            'px_frame_no' => $frame_no,
            'px_frame_amo' => $frame_amo,
            'px_lens_typeamo' => $lens_typeamo,
            'px_labo' => $labo,
            'px_total' => $total,
            'px_saleslady' => $saleslady,
            'px_doctor' => $doctor
        );

    $this->db->insert('tblitem',$item);

}
```

Here is my database:

[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgAal.png)
not sure what to change anymore :'< please help. Thanks!

Comment: What about controller part as form will be hitting controller function ?

Comment: can you do a print_r($item); and see whether the array is correct or not ?

Answer (score 0):

it's should be

Controller :

```
public function addItem() {

    $patient_name = $this->input->post('patient_name');
    $age = $this->input->post('age');
    $date = $this->input->post('date');
    $grade = $this->input->post('grade');
    $frame_no = $this->input->post('frame_no');
    $frame_amo = $this->input->post('frame_amo');
    $lens_typeamo = $this->input->post('lens_typeamo');
    $labo = $this->input->post('labo');
    $total = $this->input->post('total');
    $saleslady = $this->input->post('saleslady');
    $doctor = $this->input->post('doctor');

    $item = array(
        'px_name' => $patient_name,
        'px_age' => $age,
        'px_date' => $date,
        'px_grade' => $grade,
        'px_frame_no' => $frame_no,
        'px_frame_amo' => $frame_amo,
        'px_lens_typeamo' => $lens_typeamo,
        'px_labo' => $labo,
        'px_total' => $total,
        'px_saleslady' => $saleslady,
        'px_doctor' => $doctor
    );

    $this->db->insert($item);
}
```

Model :

```
public function insert($item)
{
  $this->db->insert('tblitem', $data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**controller**

```
    public function addItem()
    {
    $item=array(  
        'patient_name' = $this->input->post('patient_name'),
        'age' = $this->input->post('age'),
        'date' = $this->input->post('date'),
        'grade' = $this->input->post('grade'),
        'frame_no' = $this->input->post('frame_no'),
        'frame_amo' = $this->input->post('frame_amo'),
        'lens_typeamo' = $this->input->post('lens_typeamo'),
        'labo' = $this->input->post('labo'),
        'total' = $this->input->post('total'),
        'saleslady' = $this->input->post('saleslady'),
        'doctor' = $this->input->post('doctor'),     
        );
        $this->ModelName->addItem($item); 
    }
```

**model**

```
    public function addItem($item)
    {  
    $this->db->insert('tblitem', $item);
    $this->db->update('users');
    }
```

Comment: Replace your model name in the correct name and try the above code for controller and model

Answer (score 0):

controller's code :
   public function add_item()

{

$data=array(

'patient_name' = $this->input->post('patient_name'),

'age' = $this->input->post('age'),

'date' = $this->input->post('date'),

'grade' = $this->input->post('grade'),

'frame_no' = $this->input->post('frame_no'),

'frame_amo' = $this->input->post('frame_amo'),

'lens_typeamo' = $this->input->post('lens_typeamo'),

'labo' = $this->input->post('labo'),

'total' = $this->input->post('total'),

'saleslady' = $this->input->post('saleslady'),

'doctor' = $this->input->post('doctor'),

);

$this>load->model('model_name');

$this->model_name->add_item($data);

}

```
  model's code :

  public function add_item($data){
```

$this->db->insert('table_name',$data);

}

Dont forget to check the .htaccess file and base_url